# contourf plot for relative distribution of temperature measurements

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, contour, contourf

So we do a lot of temperature measurements on different days, where each measurement series can have a different number of individual measurements.

Now I want to draw a `matplotlib` `contourf` plot, where `X` should be the number of the respective day, `Y` going from 0% to 100%, and `Z` should be the temperature.

With this contour plot I can see for example: 15% of the measurements are below 12 °C (or something like this).

This is what I came up with so far:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import default_rng

rng = default_rng()

# three temperature measurements on days 5, 15 and 30
# "times 10" for scaling
temperatures_day5 = np.abs(rng.standard_normal(168)*10)
temperatures_day15 = np.abs(rng.standard_normal(212)*10)
temperatures_day30 = np.abs(rng.standard_normal(178)*10)

# for now I am only interested in temperatures between 5°C and 15°C
# 100 bins from 5 to 15 including +/- inf
bins = np.insert(np.append(np.linspace(5,15,99), float("inf")), 0, -float("inf"))

# sort measurements per day into bins
out_day5 = pd.cut(temperatures_day5, bins=bins, include_lowest=True,)
out_day15 = pd.cut(temperatures_day15, bins=bins, include_lowest=True,)
out_day30 = pd.cut(temperatures_day30, bins=bins, include_lowest=True,)

# count bins
out_day5_bin = pd.DataFrame(out_day5).squeeze().value_counts(sort=False)
out_day15_bin = pd.DataFrame(out_day15).squeeze().value_counts(sort=False)
out_day30_bin = pd.DataFrame(out_day30).squeeze().value_counts(sort=False)

X = [5, 15, 30]
Y = np.linspace(0,100,100)
Z = pd.concat([out_day5_bin, out_day15_bin, out_day30_bin,], axis=1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)

ax.contourf(X, Y, Z)
```

giving me:

[image: incorrect contourf plot]

There's already a lot of good stuff there, but ... quite obviously, the crucial trick is still missing.

Would you be so kind as to nudge me in the right direction? Thank you very much!

**EDIT:**

As per [@medium-dimensional's request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74212882/contourf-plot-for-relative-distribution-of-temperature-measurements?noredirect=1#comment131026840_74212882), here is a clumsy mockup of what I have in mind. The three levels indicate different bins of the measured temperatures (e.g. red is 5°C and below, orange between 5°C and 10°C, and blue 10°C and above). As a readout example: On day 15 (x axis), around 38% (y axis) of the measured temperatures were at 5°C or below (red area).

[image: mockup diagram]

Comment: Can you share any image that is close to expected output?

Comment: @medium-dimensional Thanks! I added an example image.